# Possible Webkit Bug With CSS3 Transitions

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

So, I'm experimenting with CSS3 transitions now that it's somewhat standardized and we don't have a whack load of prefixes to deal with. What I have is a basic three lined navigation bar, that when clicked, the two bars go on angles and the middle on disappears (in this example it stays there, but in my project it "vanishes" into an element that appears behind it that happens to be the same colour). The top and bottom bars are pseudo elements and the middle on is just the normal element.

It's hard to explain, so I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbmXW/3/).

The issue I'm having is that in Chrome 29, there is a delay in the color transition of the bars. In Firefox and IE10 the transition works. In Chrome the translate transition works, but the background color does not. In Opera, neither work, and in Safari... well, Safari has it's own problems.

The mark-up is simple:

```
<nav>
   <div id="menu">
      <span></span>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 and I'm using this very complicated script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('nav').toggleClass('active');
});

});
```

And I'm using the following CSS:

```
#menu { cursor: pointer; height: 30px; position: fixed; z-index: 200; }

#menu span { position: relative; margin-top: 10px; }

#menu span, #menu span:before, #menu span:after { height: 5px; background-color: #231F20; width: 50px; display: block; transition: all 0.5s; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; -o-transition: all 0.5s;  }

#menu.active span:before, #menu.active span:after { background-color: #F2F2F2; }

#menu.active span:before { top: 0; transform: rotate(45deg); -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); }

#menu.active span:after { bottom: 0; transform: rotate(-45deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); }

#menu span:before, #menu span:after { position: absolute; display: block; content: "";  }

#menu span:before { top: -10px; }

#menu span:after { bottom: -10px; }
```

So, my question is: Why is there no transition in Chrome on the background color? And what am I doing wrong in Opera? I know Opera now often relies on -webkit- prefixes, so I assume that whatever the problem is on one, it is on the other.

And, if you really feel like a problem solving genius, can you tell me why it just goes wonky on Safari too? That's for a gold star and a cookie if you can get it.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: transitions for pseudo elements have been borky in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I changed the CSS to be:

```
   #menu { cursor: pointer; height: 30px; position: fixed; z-index: 200; }

   #menu span { position: relative; margin-top: 10px; }

   #menu span, #menu span:before, #menu span:after { height: 5px; background-color: #231F20; width: 50px; display: block; transition: all 0.5s; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; -o-transition: all 0.5s;  }

   #menu.active span:before, #menu.active span:after { background-color: #F2F2F2; }

   #menu.active span:before { -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg); transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg); }

  #menu.active span:after { -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg); transform: translateY(0) rotate(45deg); }

  #menu span:before, #menu span:after { position: absolute; display: block; content: "";  }

  #menu span:before { -webkit-transform: translateY(-250%); transform: translateY(-250%); }

  #menu span:after { -webkit-transform: translateY(250%); transform: translateY(250%); }
```

And it works. You can see it on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbmXW/4/).